# Creating a New Instance of a Subclass from within a Baseclass

Tags: php

I want to be able to first create a new instance of a base class, then from within that base class I want to be able to create a new instance of a subclass.  I also want to be able to call base class methods from within the subclass.  I tried it with the code below and it works how I want, but is this a bad practice and is it memory efficient?  Any other comments?

```
<?php
class BaseClass {
    private $subclass = NULL;
   function __construct() {
       print "In BaseClass constructor<br>";
       $this->subclass = new SubClass();
   }
   function sayhello() {
    print 'hello from base class';
   }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
   function __construct() {
       print "In SubClass constructor<br>";
       $this->sayhello();
   }

   function saygoodbye($num) {
    print 'goodbye from base class';
   }
}

$SUB = new SubClass();
?>
```

My intention of doing this was to be able to access everything by using `$this->`, like how CodeIgniter works.  This is what I have in the index.php file for my private API.  I want to be able to authenticate the API request before calling call_user_func_array().  I also need to connect with a database for the authentication, but I want to be able to access the DB from the subclass as well.  Essentially, the code figures out what API method is being called, then creates an instance of the subclass and finally calls the method.

```
$get_contents = $_GET;

$resource_name = $get_contents['_resource'];
unset($_GET['_resource']);

$resource_method = $get_contents['_resource_method'];
unset($_GET['_resource_method']);

//Load the resource class
include 'core/resources/' . $resource_name . '.php';

//If set to true, each method will require an API key to be used
$auth_required = array();
$auth_required['collections']['addcollection'] = TRUE;

if(isset($auth_required[$resource_name][$resource_method]) && $auth_required[$resource_name][$resource_method] == TRUE) {
    print 'requires auth';
}

//Create a new instance of the resource
$API = new $resource_name();

$method_params = $_GET;

call_user_func_array(array(&$API, $resource_method), $method_params);
```

Comment: The reason you have to let BaseClass have a property of subclass instance?

Comment: What possible reason would you need the subclass stored in the base class? It is bad practice and doesn't seem to give you anything you wouldn't have already.

Comment: It was one of the ways I thought of building a REST API for my website, but will only be used by me.  Originally I had it setup to create a new instance of the subclass, then the subclass constructor can call the base class constructor.  Then to call the subclass method, I used call_user_func_array().  I'm trying to implement simple authentication using an API key that just checks to see if it exists in the database.  Basically the subclass contains all the individual methods that can be called and the base class contains methods like sendResponse().

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any efficiency issue give your current code.It depends on PRACTICAL situations. If you are asking if its allowed or not THAT is also design issue .Means depends on the PROBLEM DOMAIN. Therefore instead of asking such questions you should familiarize yourself with [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).

Understanding design patterns will give you insight into how design and architectural problems are being address in standard way and how a specific programming language addresses these issues.